# Integration of Maurer-Cartan form

Tags: lie-groups, integration

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $g$. As it is well known the Maurer-Cartan form $ω:TG\rightarrow g$ transports any vector $X\in T_{x}G$ to the start $l_{x^{-1}*}(X)\in g$, $l_{x^{-1}}$ denoting the left translation. Let $σ:[0,1]\rightarrow G$ a smooth path on $G$. It there a way to define path integration on $G$ such that $\int_{σ}{ω}=σ(1)σ(0)^{-1}$?

Comment: This is only a heuristic comment: if such a formula existed it would show that the integral of $\omega$ depended  only on the endpoints  of the path so $\omega$ would be closed. This would violate the Maurer-Cartan equation $d\omega+\frac{1}{2}[\omega,\omega]=0$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu, yes this is the case for R-valued forms and usual integration. But here we have a (possibly non abelian Lie group) and we are asking for an integration independent of path, although $ω$ may be not exact. However, $ω$ is integrable. A motivation for my question was the book: Sharpe, Differential Geometry (Springer) pages 118-126.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tangent bundle of the Lie group  is canonically trivialized, by left or right translations (depending on your conventions).  The Maurer-Cartan $1$-form defines a  connection on the tangent bundle and the Maurer-Cartan equation state that this connection is flat.   Thus the parallel transport of this connection along a loop   depends only on the homotopy type of that loop. In particular, if the group  is simply connected, the parallel  transport along any loop is trivial. Thus, the parallel  transport along a path depends only on its endpoints. The integral  of $\omega$  along a path should be defined to be this parallel transport. (I think this parallel transport is ${\rm  Ad}_{\sigma(1)\sigma(0)^{-1}}$, depending on how you choose your conventions: Lie algebra - space of left/right invariant vector fields.)

**Remark.** Let me point out a nice fact. Pick an ${\rm Ad}$-invariant homogeneous polynomial  of degree $k$ on the Lie algebra  of  $G$.  On   $TG$ there are two natural connections: the trivial connection  $\nabla^0$ and the connection $\nabla^\omega$ determined  by the Maurer-Cartan  form $\omega$. *Both connections are flat!*.

The Chern-Weil  construction associates  to the polynomial $P$  and each $G$-connection $\nabla$ on $TG$  an closed form $P(\nabla)$ of degree $2k$. This form vanishes  if $\nabla is flat$. Moreover, for any connections $\nabla',\nabla$ on $TG$ there exists a canonical  *transgression* form $TP(\nabla',\nabla)$ of degree $2k-1$  such that
$$
P(\nabla')-P(\nabla)= dTP(\nabla',\nabla).
$$ 
Applying this to our connections $\nabla^0,\nabla^\omega$ we  deduce that $TP(\nabla^\omega, \nabla^0)$  is a closed form  of degree $2k-1$.   According to C. Chevalley the  close forms $TP(\nabla^\omega, \nabla^0)$ generate the cohomology *ring*  with real coefficients of the Lie group when $P$ runs through the Ad-invariant homogeneous polynomials on the Lie algebra. For more details I refer to [Remark 8.1.15 of this book](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your book. It clarified lot of things. Though, may i ask: So, if , instead of the above tangent bundle on $G$, we consider the trivial primary fiber bundle $p: G\times G \rightarrow G$ with connection form the pullback  $p^*ω$ of $ω$, then this new connection is again flat, so what you just said above should be applied also here. But now the parallel transport would be $σ(1)σ(0)^{-1}$. Do you think this is right?

Comment: Yes, but this time instead of adjoint action you have  left multiplication action.  I'm almost sure about this  but you would have to check this yourself.